# How to compare values of same keys in two separate dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm sure this has been asked, my apologies for the duplication but I can't find an answer.
I need to compare two dictionaries containing the same keys but separate values (inventory management with thousands of items).  I can find pairs, which is helpful, but I need an expression that returns the value of a key in dictionary B when it is lower than the same key in dictionary A.  Here is what I have so far:

```
dictionary1 = {'A':7, 'B':8, 'C':9}

dictionary2 = {'A':2, 'B':8, 'C':22}

pairs = dict()

for key in dictionary1:
    if key in dictionary2 and dictionary1[key] ==dictionary2[key]:

        pairs[key] = dictionary1[key]

print(pairs)

{'B': 8}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Did you mean: `... and dictionary1[key] < dictionary2[key]:`?

Comment: ...yes.  Well this is embarrassing.  Thank you.

Comment: @Josh In the future, try debugging your program yourself before posting it. Check out [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert. This part is especially relevant: *"Explain [...] why each line of each method in your program is obviously correct. At some point you will be unable to do so, either because you don’t understand the method you wrote, or because it’s wrong"*. If you want more tips, check out [mre] and [ask].

Comment: Helpful article, thank you for sharing, I'll be sure to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at `deepdiff.DeepDiff` to find any changes in your dictionary (even on multiple levels):

```
from deepdiff import DeepDiff
dict_a = {'A':7, 'B':8, 'C':9}
dict_b = {'A':2, 'B':8, 'C':22}
dd = DeepDiff(dict_a, dict_b)
```

output:

```
{'values_changed': {"root['A']": {'new_value': 2, 'old_value': 7}, "root['C']": {'new_value': 22, 'old_value': 9}}}
```